# ошибка в консоли браузера Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript

[image: html]

[image: js]

[image: ошибка]

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: `<script> src='common.js'></script>` - тут Вас ничего не смущает?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, скриншоты несохранённых файлов - это ж шикарно. Мало того, что это скриншот, так ещё и браузер выполняет не этот код, а какой-то другой))) UPDATE: Хотя стоп, это ж sublime, а не vscode - возможно, для него точки вместо крестиков - это нормально...

Comment: @Qwertiy Всё правильно вы пишете, я проверил на sublime3: точки вместо крестика - это как раз несохранённые файлы.